# unable to push docker image to Gitlab container Registry

Tags: apache, gitlab, docker-registry, container-registry, docker-push

We have installed a self-hosted Gitlab Container registry on a separate server behind an Apache Proxy Server. It has its own domain with https enabled.
The Gitlab server is on a different server with a different domain.
The problem is when I try to push the image to the registry after successful login I am getting the below error:

```
docker push registry.gitlab.example.com/web/web-app:latest
The push refers to repository [registry.gitlab.example.com/web/web-app]
5f70bf18a086: Layer already exists
cf08d982110e: Pushing [==================================================>] 85.04MB
ea965826a88e: Layer already exists
d0c0422d1767: Layer already exists
bdab43a54a1f: Pushing [============> ] 67.58MB/277.7MB
8d7be0d3cbdd: Pushing [==================================================>] 20.38MB
cc2447e1835a: Pushing [==================================================>] 7.626MB
received unexpected HTTP status: 502 Bad Gateway
```

Also I noticed on registry server under v2 folder there is a directory with the name of the image and inside it has has many directories.
I am not sure is it the complete image uploaded or few layers of it.
However on the Gitlab interface under container registry I see nothing.
During the push I also observed error logs on Apache proxy server as:

```
[Sun Oct 15 15:14:46.723650 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 112606:tid 139963756689152] [client 10.70.74.186:61264] AH01097: pass request body failed to 10.70.107.12:5000 (10.70.107.12) from 10.70.74.186 ()
[Sun Oct 15 15:14:48.771432 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 112392:tid 139962682947328] (32)Broken pipe: [client 10.70.74.186:61267] AH01084: pass request body failed to 10.70.107.12:5000 (10.70.107.12)
[Sun Oct 15 15:14:48.771512 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 112392:tid 139962682947328] [client 10.70.74.186:61267] AH01097: pass request body failed to 10.70.107.12:5000 (10.70.107.12) from 10.70.74.186 ()
```

I followed all the troubleshooting available however could not fix this issue.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks